# App Crashes with "No StoreProvider<Store<State>> found." on launch. flutter redux

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-redux, flutter-redux-store

> Non-fatal Exception: package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart 29 in StoreProvider.of Error: No StoreProvider found. To fix, please try: * Using Dart 2 (required) by using the --preview-dart-2 flag * Wrapping your MaterialApp with the StoreProvider, rather than an individual Route * Providing full type information to your Store, StoreProvider and StoreConnector<State, ViewModel> If none of these solutions work, please file a bug at: https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

this issue solved for me by updating my flutter and dart version in android studio code

flutter 54.0.1 +
dart 201.9335

[image: 201.9335]